# Jira - Versions button not displayed on Project Overview tab

Tags: jira

When I go to the Overview tab of any project I get five options:
Summary, Issues, Reports, Popular Issues, Labels.

I can create Versions via the Admin tab.

However if I look at an Atlassian project I can see a 'Versions' button on the Summary page.
Tried to include a URL to it but SO will not let me.

This 'Versions' button gives a very handy report of the Versions & a version can be selected to give a detailed report of that Version.

How can I add this to my summary ?

If I add the URL params I get nothing as in
my_server:8080/browse/MY_PROJECT?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.project%3Aversions-panel

We have v6.1.2

Comment: The atlassian project is https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CEP

Answer (score 0):

Sadly I have just found at that this is only possible for SCRUM style Jira projects. I found this page '[Viewing the Version report](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/AGILE/Viewing+the+Version+Report)' which says it only works for SCRUM projects

Why JIRA Why ?
Why on earth would I not want to be able to list the issues in such a convenient way. Instead I have to create a unique filter for each version.

Answer (score -1):

The project reports such as Summary are not customizable. The Versions tab only appears after you create your first version, which is not always obvious.

Comment: We have versions on the project but this menu option is still not visible.